# Get image height Width of image after it has loaded images in angularjs template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am calling the renderimage function on ng-Click so that i get the height width of the image and i can apply to its parent container div. beacuse the slick carousel is not properly rendering the image.

And the problem with the renderImage function is that it is not waiting for the the image to render..gets executed prior to the image gets loaded.

please help

Below is my directive

```
app.directive('venueWidgetDir', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
        return {
            restrict: 'AE',
            $scope: {
                venueData: '=',
                onClickCallback: '=',
                vaidHover: '='
            },
            replace: true,
            templateUrl: "app/directives/venueWidget/venueWidget.tpl.html",
            link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {

                $scope.renderImage = function () {
                    $timeout(function () {
                        console.log("render image called");
                        // console.log("this is element");
                        console.log(element.find('.slick-slide.slick-current.slick-active > img').height);
                        var widthofslick = angular.element('#venue_slider').width();
                        if (widthofslick != null) {
                            widthofslick = widthofslick + 'px';
                            angular.element('#venue_slider > div > div > .slick-slide.slick-current.slick-active').css('width', widthofslick);
                        }
                        var heightofslick = angular.element('#venue_slider > div > div > .slick-slide.slick-current.slick-active > img').height();

                        var htofpicturecaption = angular.element('#venue_slider > div > div > .slick-slide.slick-current.slick-active').children('div').height();
                        if (heightofslick != null && htofpicturecaption != null && heightofslick != 0) {
                            console.log(htofpicturecaption);
                            console.log(heightofslick);
                            var heightofslickandtext = heightofslick + htofpicturecaption + 'px';
                            angular.element('#venue_slider > div ').css('height', heightofslickandtext);
                        }
                    }, 1500)
                }



            },

        }
    }])
```

and my template is given below

```
<div class="venue_info_wrapper">
    <div class="venue_info">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="venue in venues" ng-click="checkHover($index)">
                <div class="venue_picture" ng-click="showVenueDetails(venue.details); renderImage()">
                    <img ng-src="{{relPath + venue.thumbnail.replace('thumbnail','visu')}}" />
                </div>
                <div class="venue_identity">
                    <a href ng-class="{active:activeVenuePath == venue.details && validHover !=0}" ng-click=" showVenueDetails(venue.details) ">{{venue.title}}</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="venue_info_popup active" id="carousal">
        <div class="tab_content_wrapper">
            <div class="profile_tab_wrapper" id="profile">
                <div class="country_name">
                    <div class="cn"><span>{{venueInfo.name}}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="close_png close_profile">
                        <img src="img/arrow_left_black.png" ng-click="prevNews()" />
                        <img src="img/arrow_right_black.png" ng-click="nextNews()" />
                        <img ng-click="stopSlider()" class="close_img" src="img/close_popup2.png" style="padding-right: 20px" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="country_name_small"><span>{{venueInfo.name}}</span>
                </div>
                <div id="venue_slider" class="responsive clear slideWrap popup_slider">
                    <div ng-repeat="galleryInfo in venueInfo.gallaryImg">
                        <img ng-src="{{relPath + galleryInfo.component[2]._href}}" />
                        <div class="team_picture_caption">
                            <p>{{galleryInfo.legende.para}}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--<div>
                        <img ng-src="{{relPath + venueInfo.in._href}}" />
                        <div class="team_picture_caption">
                            <p>{{venueInfo.inPara}}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>-->
                </div>
                <div class="country_details_wrapper">
                    <div class="country_details">
                        <p ng-repeat="info in venueInfo.venuesDeatil">
                            <span class="bold_n_caps">{{info.dlabel}} :</span>
                            <span class="regular"> {{info.dtext}}</span>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @shank your question is bit unclear ..where do you apply the directive and what html your are refereeing in directive.Pls edit your question showing appropriate example without dumping so much unnecessary code.